# file_get_contents is getting the wrong content

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I'm using `file_get_contents` function in `PHP` to get data from website it's working well. But for this URL:

http://benalman.com/code/projects/php-simple-proxy/ba-simple-proxy.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F

It is not getting the actual content present there.

```
<?php
  echo file_get_contents('http://benalman.com/code/projects/php-simple-proxy/ba-simple-proxy.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.goolge.com%2F');
?>
```

Comment: Most likely some kind of redirect because http://www.youtube.com will be redirected to https. Maybe try to access the https version directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah it does return the same, but you can't see it because it's a lot of HTML and Javascript.

Here's an example to read the JSON content:

```
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
$json = file_get_contents('http://benalman.com/code/projects/php-simple-proxy/ba-simple-proxy.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2F');
print_r(json_decode($json));
```